# How to create new API Integration package for each Business Unit in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send, sfmc-business-unit

In our marketing cloud instance, we are having 2 BU.

When we are executing triggered send from new BU via REST API, we are getting error : `404 API not found` even though all triggered send definitions etc are present in this new BU. This probably is due to the fact that access token for this new BU should be different from original BU's access token. And to generate this new access token, we require clientID and clientSecret of this new BU.

So how do we get new access token/clientID/ClientSecret for new BU? I assume these would be different for different BUs.

We have an installed package for old/main/parent BU with API Integration type of component in it that has its clientId and clientSecret. When we click on "New" in this package to create a new API Integration component, it does not let me select that again, implying we can have only 1 API INt. per package.

So for the new/child BU, how do we use this API Integration component, or how do we create a new API Integration component? Do we need to install a new package for new BU and if yes how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you will need new credentials if you are using rest API or using token authentication for SOAP API. Here is a guide to create your new credentials in SFMC. Check if you have the right permission set for the task.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/install-packages.htm

P.S You will have to be on the BU you want API credentials when creating the API integration component

Comment: So you mean we need to add a new package altogether for a new BU?

Comment: Yes, as you have 2 BUs and ClientID & Client secret that you have is only for one of them. You will need a new package for the second BU.

Comment: As a note, for SOAP API you can use the ClientID attribute to switch between BUs so you would not require multiple Id/Secret combinations. (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/using_clientid_in_your_soap_api_code.htm). I believe this would still be required for REST API calls though.